# run a function and do sum with next row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
main_id    time               day      lat           long
1          2019-05-31         1        53.5501667    9.9716466  
1          2019-05-31         1        53.6101545    9.9568781
1          2019-05-30         1        53.5501309    9.9716300
1          2019-05-30         2        53.5501309    9.9716300
1          2019-05-30         2        53.4561309    9.1246300
2          2019-06-31         4        53.5501667    9.9716466
2          2019-06-31         4        53.6101545    9.9568781
```

I want to find the total distance covered by each `main_id` item for each `day`. To calculate the distance between 2 set of coordinates, I can use this function:

```
def find_kms(coords_1, coords_2):
    return geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

but I am not sure how I can sum it by grouping for `main_id` and `day`. The end result could be a new df like this:

```
main_id      day      total_dist     time
1            1        ...            2019-05-31 
1            2        ....           2019-05-31 
2            4        ....           2019-05-31
```

Where the derived `time` is any or the first value from the respective `main_id` and `day` time's column.

total_dist calculation:

For example, for the first row, for `main_id == 1` and day `1`, the total_dist would be calculated like this:

```
find_kms(( 53.5501667,9.9716466),(53.6101545,9.9568781)) + find_kms((53.6101545,   9.9568781),(53.5501309,9.9716300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your function is not vectorized hence making the work difficult.

```
(df.assign(dist = df.join(df.groupby(['main_id', 'day'])[['lat', 'long']].
   shift(), rsuffix='1').bfill().
   reset_index().groupby('index').
   apply(lambda x: find_kms(x[['lat','long']].values, x[['lat1','long1']].values))).
   groupby(['main_id', 'day'])['dist'].sum().reset_index())

  main_id  day       dist
0        1    1  13.499279
1        1    2  57.167034
2        2    4   6.747748
```

Another option will be to use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def total_dist(x):
    coords = x[['lat', 'long']].values
    lam = lambda x,y: (find_kms(x[1],y) + x[0],y)
    dist = reduce(lam, coords, (0,coords[0]))[0]
    return pd.Series({'dist':dist})

df.groupby(['main_id', 'day']).apply(total_dist).reset_index()
 
   main_id  day       dist
0        1    1  13.499351
1        1    2  57.167033
2        2    4   6.747775
```

## EDIT:

If count is needed:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'count':df.groupby(['main_id', 'day']).main_id.count()}).
   join(df.groupby(['main_id', 'day']).apply(total_dist)))
Out[157]: 
             count       dist
main_id day                  
1       1        3  13.499351
        2        2  57.167033
2       4        2   6.747775
```

Comment: Can I modify this such that we can also add another column ```count```that gives the number of times a ```main_id```occurs for each day. For example, for the first row, the value of ```count``` would be ```3```. Then for the second row (id 1, day 2), ```count```would be ```2```.

Comment: @Jbd. Just `df.groupby(['main_id', 'day'])['main_id'].count()` should do. Also if the solution above answers your question feel free to accept it as the solution

Comment: ```df.groupby(['vehicle_id', 'day']).apply(total_dist).reset_index()```works if I assign it to a new ```df_new```. But then how will I get the count? I guess it should be before this part? If I do this ```df_new['count'] = df.groupby(['vehicle_id', 'day'])['vehicle_id'].count()``` after the last step, it would throw an error

Comment: Do the two separately and before you reset the index, join. Note that that was not part of the original question. I believe the answer given is complete and I recommend accepting it as the solution

Comment: @Jbd `(df.assign(count = 1).groupby(['main_id', 'day']).agg({'time':min, 'count':len})
.join(df.groupby(['main_id', 'day']).apply(total_dist)))`

Comment: @jbd Note that I did `df.assign(count = 1)` so count does exist

Comment: If you could add comments to your code to explain the steps, it would be great! Since these are a bunch of steps joined together, it is a bit confusing for me

Comment: Just realized that the following ```df_output = (df.assign(count = 1).groupby(['vehicle_id', 'day']).agg({'time':min, 'count':len}).join(df.groupby(['vehicle_id', 'day']).apply(total_dist)))``` does not return the ```main_id```. It only returns the time, dist, and count.

Comment: @Jbd at the very end include `.reset_index()`

Comment: For the ```min```time, is it giving the min for each ```main_id``` or also for each ```main_id``` and each ```day```. In my sample data, the output seems to be a single date for all occurrences of a ```main_id```? Or is

Comment: @Jbd its giving the min. You stated that you wanted any value. You can use `max` or even `lambda x:x[0]` to get the first etc

Comment: yes any value from the same day & main_id. For example, for the first row any time value where the ```main_id``` and ```day``` = 1. This combination of main_id and day occurs thrice so we could pick any time value out of those 3. any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Jbd it seems your groups might be sharing dates for you to get a similar date eg main_id 1& day1 share the same minimum time as main id 1&day2.  Try aggregating on its own and see what happens. Other than that i do not have any more ideas

Comment: I rechecked and the dates are different. Instead of minimum, how can we select the very first value that occurs for each combination of ```main_id``` and ```day```.?

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach to convert the lat lon into utm without using `find_kms` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import utm

u= utm.from_latlon(df.lat.values,df.long.values) 
df['y'],df['x']=u[0],u[1] # lat, lon to utm meter (y=lat,x=lon)

a=df.groupby(['main_id', 'day'])[['x','y']].apply(lambda x: x.diff().replace(np.nan, 0))

df['dist']=np.sqrt(a.x**2 + a.y**2)/1000 # distance in km

df1=df.groupby(['main_id','day'])[['dist','day']].agg({'day':'count', 'dist': 'sum'}).rename(columns={'day':'day_count'})
```

df1 output:

```
             day_count       dist
main_id day                      
1       1            3  13.494554
        2            2  57.145276
2       4            2   6.745386
```

Comment: The answer here is not correct. Look at the answer I have and what you have

Comment: onyambu, thanks much for correcting me. Let me update the code.

Comment: could you recheck the last part? currently, it only gives me the ```day_count``` and distance as the output. The main_id and ```day``` would be missing @ShuvashishRoy

Comment: and the ```day_count``` is 00 for almost all rows, which I am sure is incorrect.

Comment: Are you asking me? In that case, df1 shows exactly what I have posted. Did you copy the code correctly?

Comment: If you don't know how to copy your exact sample `df` from your stackoverflow post  then use `df = pd.read_clipboard()` after selecting and copying the `df` using mouse. Then run the code.